# Android: уведомление ContentProveder о изменении данных через Cursor

Tags: android, contentprovider, java, sqlite

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как уведомить `ContentProvider` о изменении данных, только данные я изменяю не через `getContentResolver().insert() (update, delete)`, а напрямую в через `SQLiteDatabase`? Делаю так потому, что если изменять через контент провидер, то после каждого изменения на экране происходит перестроение списка, а если изменять через  `SQLiteDatabase` я могу сделать транзакцию и по её завершению хотел уведомить контент провидер что бы он 1 раз перестроил список на экране по новым данным.

Хотел вызвать метод `getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);`, но ожидаемого результата это не принесло.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();
while (objectsIterator.hasNext()) {
   String roomName = (String) objectsIterator.next();
   JSONObject room = notificationsObj.getJSONObject(roomName);
   notification = createNotification(roomName, room, notification);

   cv.put("_id", notification.id);
   cv.put("messages_count", notification.messages_count);
   cv.put("create_date", notification.create_date);
   cv.put("model_name", notification.model_name);
   cv.put("sphere_id", notification.sphere_id);
   cv.put("circle_id", notification.circle_id);
   cv.put("dt", notification.dt);
   db.replace(DBHelper.NOTIFICATIONS_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
   cv.clear();
}
db.endTransaction();
mContext.getContentResolver().notifyChange(NotificationsContentProvider.NOTIFICATION_CONTENT_URI, null);
db.close();
```

Comment: Кажется я близок к разгадке тайны о транзакциях через ContentProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен: надо перегрузить метод `bilkInsert` в своем контент провидере.

```
    @Override
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] valueses) {
    if (valueses.length > 0) {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            for (ContentValues values : valueses) {
                db.insert(NOTIFICATION_TABLE, null, values);
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "NullPointerException:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```